# Load static images by path (Vue.js)

Tags: html, vue.js

An Image will show when specifically displaying the path in ,
but when I cycle through an array of paths identical to the working example above the images show as small icons or don't work at all. I believe this may be caused by the loading of static images during run-time / load-time.

I have tried creating a method (accepts full path)

```
getImgUrl(pic) {

    var images = require.context('', false, /\.png$/)

    return images('' + pic)

}
```

This is my code to place an image in each cell for each path in i_data

```
<td class="data_cell"  v-for="image, index in i_data"> 

  <div class="img_cell">

    <img src='../../../../PHOTOS/3852034250/61117-00-061568/act2.jpg' 
    width="160" max-height="220px"/> (SHOWS IMAGE)

     {{i_data[index][2]}} (SHOWS PATH OF EACH IMAGE)

     <img :src="i_data[index][2]" width="160" max-height="220px"/> (NO IMAGE - SMALL ICON)

     <!-- <img :src="require(`${i_data[index][2]}`)"/> --> (ERROR MESSAGE 1)

  </div>

<td>



i_data = [["act2", "2019-05-31 08:15:25", 
           "../../../../PHOTOS/3852034250/61117-00-061568/act2.jpg"],
          ["doggo", "2019-05-28 15:34:21", 
           "../../../../PHOTOS/3852034250/61117-00-061568/doggo.jpg"],
          ["Test", "2019-07-30 10:39:56", 
           "../../../../PHOTOS/3852034250/61117-00-061568/Test.jpg"],
          ["tree 2", "2019-07-24 10:31:25", 
           "../../../../PHOTOS/3852034250/61117-00-061568/tree.jpg"],
          ["tree", "2019-06-27 14:46:50", 
           "../../../../PHOTOS/3852034250/61117-00-061568/tree2.jpg"]]
```

ERROR MESSAGE 1:

Cannot find module '../../../../PHOTOS/3852034250/61117-00-061568/act2.jpg'.
    at webpackContextResolve (eval at ./src/components/online_services/bce_online recursive ^.*$ (app.js:6581), :34:9)

Comment: On your <img> tag the attribute src should be binded using v-bind or ":", then have to be so: :src="image"

Comment: I thought I was using v-bind on this line <img :src="i_data[index][2]">,  could you be more specific?

Comment: Did you try without use require()? also v-for="image, index in i_data" should be v-for="(image, index) in i_data", and for best legibility i_data should be a array of objects

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it like this:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    i_data: [
      {
        name: "act2",
        date: "2019-05-31 08:15:25",
        path: "https://via.placeholder.com/300/0000FF"
      },
      {
        name: "doggo",
        date: "2019-05-28 15:34:21",
        path: "https://via.placeholder.com/300/00FF00"
      },
      {
        name: "Test",
        date: "2019-07-30 10:39:56",
        path: "https://via.placeholder.com/300/FF0000"
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="data_cell" v-for="(image, index) in i_data">
      <div class="img_cell">

          {{ image.name }} {{ image.date }}

          <img :src="image.path" width="160" max-height="220px" />

          <img :src="image.path" />
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So my problem with this answer is that my paths are being generated from a php file that grabs all the image paths off the images held within a certain folder so I do not explicitly have them without getting them by indexing my data structure.

Comment: The names and dates are also generated through an axios request to my database which saves them into i_data, so i do not explicitly have them without some extraction. Do you think I can still use your method?

Comment: sure, you should return your data as associative array using json_encode.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<img :src="require('../../../../PHOTOS/3852034250/61117-00-061568/act2.jpg')" 
width="160" max-height="220px"/>
```